# Update Stock Line graph based on DateRangeInput user Selection - Shiny App

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am using stock data from `Quantmod` and looking for a way to use `DateRangeInput` within a shiny app and have the user selection be reflected in a `ggplot` graph.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Stock App"),

  mainPanel(
    selectInput("stock", "Select a Stock(s):", choices = unique(all_stocks_df$Stock), multiple = TRUE, selected = "AAPL"),
    dateRangeInput("daterange", "Select a timeframe to be plotted", start = "2010-01-01", end = "2020-01-01")),

  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Line Graph", plotOutput("line"))

  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$line <- renderPlot({
    stock_subset <- subset(all_stocks_df, Stock == input$stock)
    ggplot () + 
      geom_line(aes(x=input$daterange, y=Close, color = Stock),
                data = stock_subset)
  })


}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

The `all_stocks_df` dataframe I am generating the plot with looks like this:

```
Date       Close     Stock 
2019-12-31 293.65     AAPL 
... 
2007-01-03 11.97      AAPL 

2019-12-31 1847.84    AMZN 
... 
2007-01-03 38.70      AMZN
```

When I enter `input$daterange` as my X argument for my `ggplot` line graph, it is not working. Ideally the user would change the timeframe and the graph would update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For subset would use `%in%` instead of `==` since you can have multiple stocks selected in your `selectInput`. Also would filter/subset by `input$daterange` before plotting.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$line <- renderPlot({
    stock_subset <- subset(all_stocks_df, Stock %in% input$stock & Date>= input$daterange[1] & Date <= input$daterange[2])
    ggplot () + 
      geom_line(aes(x=Date, y=Close, color = Stock), data = stock_subset)
  })
}
```